# Changing the view of a document set on a web part page

Tags: 2010, document-set, view

I've created a web part page and pulled in a document set as a web part, the document set was created and is being used elsewhere with the default view. I've modified the top level view of the web part but once you go into one of the document sets it reverts back to the default view rather than using my modified view. I can't change the view inside the document set without affecting the original view. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using a content editor with text that linked to the relevant document set view.